# IE8 Fancybox scrollbar slider size not matching content

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

So I am using Fancybox 1.3.1, and jquery 1.4.2.  When the fancybox is displayed, I have a bunch of content in the fancybox that exceeds its height, so a vertical scrollbar is shown.  On every browser except IE 8, everything works as expected.  In IE8 all of the content is loaded, however, the slider of the scrollbar takes up almost the entire height of the scrollbar, and as you scroll down, the slider decreases in size (to match the amount of content).  I want the slider size to be the small size it should be as displayed in other browsers when the fancybox is loaded.

[Image comparison of the two browers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRDhA.jpg)

The left of the below image shows what IE8 looks like, and the right is Chrome.

Here is the fancybox code

```
    $("#a.lightboxLink").fancybox({
                'frameHeight': 400, 
                'frameWidth': 650, 
                'padding': 10, 
                'hideOnContentClick': false, 
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false, 
                'showPrint': true               });
```

I want both to look like the Chrome example.

Does anyone know what could be the cause?  Is it a jquery compatibility issue?  There are not any errors on the chrome development console, so I am not sure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fancybox v1.3.1 then check for the right API options [here](http://fancybox.net/api). You are actually using the old API options for version 1.2.x.

Additionally, none of the versions 1.2.x or 1.3.x have a `showPrint` option.

IE is pickier with small syntax or js errors that other browsers may overlook. Also check that you have the proper `DOCTYPE` and that the `DOCTYPE` is the very first line of your html document (no preceding spaces or comments)